# I want to download files from GCP bucket on local computer however it shows path error one deployed on GAE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

The download path works locally however once deployed GAE shows path error and I want user to have a simple browser download file. Right now what I do is store it in a /tmp folder than download. Has anyone done a file download from gcp bucket once the app is deployed in standard environment using python3.

Answer (score 0):

While you can write to the /tmp folder as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features), keep in mind that App Engine creates and deletes containers for you dynamically. As such it is against best practices to write anything to the disk.

For these use cases, what is recommended it for you to write and read directly from a GCS bucket as mentioned on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage).

I hope you find this information useful!